# push notification working in development profile but issue in distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5, push-notification

I have create two diffrent App id for development and distribution profile but facing an issue for get notification for distribution profile but its work on development profile. anyone give me check .pem file correct or not

Comment: Did you create PEM file for distribution?

Comment: yes already done and it's sent to backend replace it

Comment: Is your app being distributed through the App Store? Or are you running it from Xcode?

Comment: main problem is that Application is live on iTunes. so, i cant want to recreate app id

Comment: @Code distributed through the App Store

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with PEM´s without pass. Create them with a pass and try again.
If you have access to your server log, yo can check APNS server response, sometimes it gave clues on what is going on.
Also check if your devices´ tokens are correctly stored in server.

Comment: yes, I have try with pass and try all things that you have mention but not solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following scenarios and execute.

1. In the firewalls need to check the 2195, 2196 ports and also check gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, gateway.push.apple.com
2. Sign your application using distribution profiles and run the application in distribution mode. Make sure if you are running the application using distribution mode then in server side also should use distribution PEM files. I believe you are made the mistake in this scenario.